# Why don't these two ways of querying get the same result?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a query that results in an ActiveRecord::Relation:

```
> query.class
=> ActiveRecord::Relation
```

Usually these two expressions yield the same results, but I have a problem where they yield different results:

```
query.pluck(:id).uniq.sort
query.map(&:id).uniq.sort
```

For example:
`[14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 25, 321, 322, 323, 324, 325]`
vs
`[310, 311, 312, 313, 314, 315, 316, 317, 318, 319, 320, 321, 322, 323, 324, 325]`

The query in question is a paging query. I have 116 sample users and the query is:
`"SELECT  users.* FROM users WHERE users.company_id = 2 LIMIT 25 OFFSET 100"`

It's not clear to me why that should ever be the case, or what I should be looking for. Any suggestions as to why they might be different?

[The documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck) suggests they should be equivalent.

Comment: How are your results different?

Comment: Can you share the output of the two queries.

Comment: @KirtiThorat @Agis  I have updated to show the difference, and using `sort` to make it clear that it isn't just ordering, it's different ids.

Comment: What is the query that you are firing? query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query:

```
SELECT users.* FROM users WHERE users.company_id = 2 LIMIT 25 OFFSET 100
```

doesn't have an ORDER BY clause so you have no reason to expect any particular 25 rows to come back. Keep in mind that the rows in a table have no natural order so you always need to explicitly specify an order if you need a specific order.

Add an ORDER BY and you should get the same results from both the `pluck` and `map` approaches.